# Jsch sftp exception : file not found (even if the file exists)

Tags: java, python, shell, jython, jsch

I'm writing a jython code which use Jsch to run some shell instructions on a remote machine. I need to wait a specific shell instruction has finished before continuing the exectuion of the jython code on my local machine (=need to synchronize shell code on a remote machine).

To do that, when the specific shell instruction has finished i create a text file in the remote machine. Then in my jython code I open an sftp channel and try periodically to get the file (using the sftp.exception and a "while true" loop). The code wait until the file is downloaded.

My problem is that even when the file is created, the jsch function "get" doesn't manage to download the file and keep sending "sftp.exception : no such file or directory" .That makes me locked up in an infinite loop.

Here is my code :

```
    #We generate the info files for each class of the classlist            
        for classname in classlist:

            print ("Generating information file (format : .out) for the class %s " % (classname))

        #We open a shell channel and run the commands "windchill shell" and then "InfoReport.sh classname".            
            channel_generate = gl_session.openChannel('shell')
            ops = channel_generate.getOutputStream()

            ps = PrintStream(ops, True)                 
            channel_generate.connect()
            ps.println("windchill shell")
            ps.println('rm ' + self.wt_home + '/tmp/' + classname + '.txt')
     #The following instruction is the one i need to synchronize                   
            ps.println(self.wt_home + '/bin/' + self.command + " " + classname)
     #I create a file to detect the end of the previous instruction
            ps.println('echo ok > ' + self.wt_home + '/tmp/' + classname)
            ps.println('exit')
            ps.close()


        #Here we wait until the synchro file is created. 
        #We connect an sftp server and test every 4 seconds if we can retrieve the file.
            channel_synchro = gl_session.openChannel('ftp')
            channel_synchro.connect()

        #This loop is broken when the get is successful
            while True:
                try:
                    channel_synchro.get(self.wt_home + '/tmp/' + classname,'/home/dev/temp')
                    break
                except jsch.SftpException:
                    time.sleep(4) 

       #Disconnect and close de sftp channel
            channel_synchro.disconnect()
            channel_synchro.close()  


       #Disconnect and close the shell channel
            channel_generate.disconnect()
            channel_generate.close()
```

I have tried different solutions : other type of loops, create a new channel in each iteration of the "while true" loop, i have thought about user rights problem, i have checked if the paths are exact and they are, i have checked if the sftp function of my machine works and it works.
Nothing works, i'm still not able to solve this problem

Comment: You should get a stacktrace and track down what exactly the JSCH code is trying to do when it throws. That exception could be referring to the local file, for example.

Comment: @Kenster I've get the stacktrace and identified the source of the problem in the api. At the line channel_synchro.get(...), the api doesn't like the variable "classname". When I replace it by a normal string or another string variable it works. I guess it's because "classname" is used as an iterator and the automatic jython conversion of a python string iterator to a classic java string doesn't work well. Thanks for your advice!